# String length evaluation in C

Tags: python, c

I am very new to programming. I have a little bit of experience with Python, and I am trying to write one of my Python programs in C.

Two of the lines of code in my program are as follows:

```
if len(name) <= 20:
    print("text here")
```

len(name) in Python evaluates the number of characters in the string name, then implements the following code if there are 20 or fewer characters. I just need to know it's equivalent in C.

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe something like `if (strlen(name)<=20) printf ("test here\n");`?

Comment: That was code from my Python program.

Comment: @Darman12 Then your python program doesn't even compile due to syntax error.

Comment: You dropped the colon.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the full program. Do you want me to?

Comment: For future reference, Google can solve questions like this quicker than the time needed to write up a question and get a response. First Google result for `c string length`: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Length.html

Comment: Note that `strlen` can be a lot slower than the equivalent Python, since C doesn't actually store a string's length with the string. Instead, `strlen` has to go through the whole string to find the null byte at the end. To avoid performance issues, it's often useful to keep track of the length of a string you're working with in a way that minimizes `strlen` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent C code:

```
if (strlen(name) <= 20)
{
    //code
}
```